# MVC controller method is not being called from ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

MVC controller method is not being called from the ajax i have declared. PFB the code snippet
C# Controller:

```
public ActionResult Checkfunction(string ReqID, string AssociateId, string AssetId)
{
      MyDetails obj = new MyDetails();
      List<string> Lst = new List<string>();
      Lst = obj.Check(AssociateId, AssetId, ReqID);
      return this.Json(Lst, "text/json");
}
```

Javascript code (ajax call): refering details controller, and webmethod Checkfunction

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("Details/Checkfunction")',
    data: { 'ReqID': RequestId, 'AssociateId': AssociateID, 'AssetId': Host_Name },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        if (data.length > 0) {

                ViewModel.REQUESTID() = data[0];
                ViewModel.FLAG() = '1';
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            ViewModel.FLAG() = '0';
            ViewModel.REQUESTID() = '';
        }

        if (ViewModel.REQUESTID() != '' || ViewModel.REQUESTID() != null) {
            debugger;
            ViewModel.REQID() = RequestId;
        }
    },

    error: function (error) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: how come the Checkfunction is not in your ajax call?

Comment: your ajax url is pointed to `PhoenixInbox/CheckMSDNRemap`, but your method is `Checkfunction`?  That would be a good starting point

Comment: What does GetUrl() do?

Comment: simply change the url  properties to `url: '/PhoenixInbox/Checkfunction'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nowadays it's better to use promises, and if you're going to return json, it's better return JsonResult instead of ActionResult

http://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just registered today, I have several things to learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
url: '/PhoenixInbox/Checkfunction',
data: { 'ReqID': RequestId, 'AssociateId': AssociateID, 'AssetId': Host_Name },
contentType: "application/json",
success: function (data) {
    debugger;
    if (data.length > 0) {

            ViewModel.REQUESTID() = data[0];
            ViewModel.FLAG() = '1';
    }
    else {
        debugger;
        ViewModel.FLAG() = '0';
        ViewModel.REQUESTID() = '';
    }

    if (ViewModel.REQUESTID() != '' || ViewModel.REQUESTID() != null) {
        debugger;
        ViewModel.REQID() = RequestId;
    }
},

error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
```

Controller:

```
[Httppost]
public ActionResult Checkfunction(string ReqID, string AssociateId, string AssetId)
{
      MyDetails obj = new MyDetails();
      List<string> Lst = new List<string>();
      Lst = objMyAssetsDetails.Check(AssociateId, AssetId, ReqID);
      return this.Json(Lst, "text/json");
}
```

Comment: '/PhoenixInbox/Checkfunction' could blow up in production if the app is not deployed in root directory.  So the url should be built with 'Url.Action' at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build the url correctly:

   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   url: '**@Url.AbsoluteAction("PhoenixInbox", "Checkfunction")**',
2. Make sure you allow get on Get action: **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet**

   public ActionResult Checkfunction(string ReqID, string AssociateId, string AssetId)
   {
         MyDetails obj = new MyDetails();
         List Lst = new List();
         Lst = objMyAssetsDetails.Check(AssociateId, AssetId, ReqID);
         return this.Json(Lst, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
   }